# Using guard to minify javascript files into a different directory

Tags: javascript, ruby, guard

I am trying to create my first guardfile and have run into difficulties trying to minify some of my javascript files.

I want guard to watch the 'app/assets/js' directory and any time a file is changed within this directory, for a minified version of the file to be created within 'public/js' with the same name and if possible within the same directory name.

For example were I to save the bootstrap.js file within app/assets/js/vendor I would like for the minified version to be placed within the public/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js file.

Below are the relevant parts of my current guardfile:

```
require 'cssmin'
require 'jsmin'

module ::Guard
  class Refresher < Guard
  end
end

# 
guard :refresher do
  watch('public/css/styles.min.css') do |m|
    css = File.read(m[0])
    File.open(m[0], 'w') { |file| file.write(CSSMin.minify(css)) }
  end
  watch(%r[app/assets/js/.+]) do |m|
    js = File.read(m[0])
    File.open(m[0], 'w') { |file| file.write(JSMin.minify(js)) }
  end
end
```

This is my first experience of Ruby and so beginner orientated answers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Howq do I get guard to watch the 'app/assets/js' directory and any time a file is changed within this directory, for a minified version of the file to be created within 'public/js' with the same name and if possible within the same directory name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write to the same file you're reading. According to your question, you need something like:

```
watch(%r[app/assets/js/(.+)]) do |m|
  File.write("public/js/#{ m[1] }", JSMin.minify(File.read(m[0])))
end
```

Please note the capture group I've added to the regexp, so I can grab the filename with `m[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helped. I modified the regex to %r[app/assets/js/(.+)\.js] and then changed the second line to File.open("public/js/#{ m[1] }.min.js", 'w+') { |file| file.write(JSMin.minify(File.read(m[0])))} so as to create a .min.js file in the public/js directory. I noticed you are a guard core team member and just wanted to thank you and the rest of the team for making an excellent plugin. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Glad I could help.